# SQL LIMIT dynamic N

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I want to get the (last row) average air_temperature from all stations that have the specified county_number.

Therefor, my solution would be something like

```
SELECT AVG(air_temperature) 
  FROM weather 
 WHERE station_id IN (
       SELECT station_id 
         FROM stations 
        WHERE county_number = 25
       )
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
```

Clearly, this does not give the correct row as it returns the average air_temperature based on all air_temperature ever recorded of one station.

Back to the problem, I want to get the average air_temperature over the last inserted row from each station that have the specified county_number.

**Table weather**

```
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| station_id       | char(20)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| timestamp        | timestamp   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| air_temperature  | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Table stations**

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| station_id    | char(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| county_number | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Tables are minimized

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this with a `join` and some filtering:

```
select avg(w.air_temperature)
from weather w join
     stations s
     on w.station_id = s.station_id
where s.county_number = 25 and
      w.timestamp = (select max(w2.timestamp) from weather w2 where w2.station_id = w.station_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last inserted row by checking the `max(timestamp)`:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(w.air_temperature) 
FROM weather w 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT station_id, max(timestamp) maxtimestamp FROM weather GROUP BY station_id        
) t
ON w.station_id = t.station_id AND w.timestamp = t.maxtimestamp
WHERE 
  w.station_id IN (SELECT station_id FROM stations WHERE county_number = 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that your `timestamp` column is nullable and you are talking about the "last inserted row". That is the one with the greatest ID. Hence:

As of MySQL 8 you can use window functions in order to read the table only once:

```
select avg(air_temperature) 
from
(
  select air_temperature, id, max(id) over (partition by station_id) as max_id
  from weather 
  where station_id in (select station_id from stations where county_number = 25)
) analyzed
where id = max_id;
```

In older versions you must read the table twice:

```
select avg(air_temperature) 
from weather 
where (station_id, id) in
(
  select station_id, max(id)
  from weather 
  where station_id in (select station_id from stations where county_number = 25)
  group by station_id
);
```